# Creating a Meeting in JSON Format issue

Tags: xpages

Is there any way to create a Calendar entry using a mailfile where the Organizer is not the mailfile Owner?

For example:

http://mycompanycom/mail/utils.nsf/api/calendar/events

I want to use a gereric mailfile where DAS is enabled and make all request against it; otherwise I'll need to query every Organizer's mailfile.

The only way I can make it to work is when I set the organizer the same as the mailfile owner, for example:
http://mycompany.com/mail1/ndev1.nsf/api/calendar/events

Here Notes Dev1 is the Owner for ndev1.nsf

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "summary": "TEST FEB 2018",
            "location": "TEST LOCATION - NOT NEEDED",
            "description": "",
            "CalendarDateTime": {
                "date": "2018-02-26",
                "time": "17:00:00",
                "utc": true
            },
            "start": {
                "date": "2018-02-26",
                "time": "17:00:00",
                "utc": true
            },
            "end": {
                "date": "2018-02-26",
                "time": "18:00:00",
                "utc": true
            },
            "class": "public",
            "transparency": "opaque",
            "sequence": 0,
            "x-lotus-noticetype": "I",
            "attendees": [
                {
                    "role": "chair",
                    "status": "accepted",
                    "rsvp": false,
                    "displayName": "Notes Dev1/MYCOMPANY",
                    "email": "notes.dev1@mycompany.com"
                },
                {
                        "role": "req-participant",
                        "status": "needs-action",
                        "rsvp": true,
                        "displayName": "Pablo Solano/MYCOMPANY",
                        "email": "pablo.solano@mycompany.com"
                        },
                        {
                        "role": "req-participant",
                        "status": "needs-action",
                        "rsvp": true,
                        "displayName": "Notes Dev2/MYCOMPANY",
                        "email": "notes.dev2@mycomany.com"
                        },
                    {
                    "role": "req-participant",
                    "userType": "room",
                    "status": "accepted",
                    "rsvp": true,
                    "email": "maar@teradyne.com"
                    }
            ],
            "organizer": {
                "displayName": "Notes Dev1/MYCOMPANY",
                "email": "notes.dev1@mycompany.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I found this url: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ndseforum.nsf/xpTopicThread.xsp?documentId=CB20A0E36EE82AB385258154003B0A86

with this text:

One important caveat:  The organizer property must match the owner of the database as specified in the request URL (/{database}/api/calendar/events).

Answer (score 0):

I see few options for you:

1. Quick&dirty - change/add current user as owner of the calendar on the fly every time. Not recommended.
2. Make your code to work on behalf of universal identity, which is also owner of the calendar. Caveat: meeting will be arranged by that identity.
3. Create the meeting from user's calendar. Probably that's not what you want.

Comment: Thanks @Frantisek Kossuth

Comment: Thanks @Frantisek Kossuth. Option #1 could work, but, there is a chance than more than one request is submitted at the same time. Option #2 The problem with this one is that if one of the recepients (users or room) declines the invite, then the email will be sent back to this universal identity instead to the real person who made the request.  Question here; is there any way to pass over the username and password to the POST request.

Comment: Option #3 The problem here is that I have to enable DAS in every mail file. The application where the request is initiated is not in the Users's Mail Home Server so its complaining about Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.